# Haskell Error: Variable not in scope: guard :: Bool -> Maybe a0

Tags: haskell

whats kind of Error is this?

```
error:Variable not in scope: guard :: Bool -> Maybe a0
```

thats the Code

```
eval3 :: Exp -> Maybe Integer
eval3 e =
  case e of
    (Const x) -> pure x
    (ExpAdd x y) -> eval3 x >>= \x' -> eval3 y >>= \y' -> return (x'+y')
    (ExpMult x y) -> eval3 x >>= \x' -> eval3 y >>= \y' -> return (x'*y')
    (ExpDiv x y) -> eval3 x >>= \x' -> eval3 y >>= (\y' -> guard (y'/=0) >> return (div x'y'))
```

Answer (score 5):

[`guard`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:guard) is in `Control.Monad`, not `Prelude`. You just need to `import Control.Monad` at the top of your file.

Answer (score 1):

As @SilvioMoyolo says, you need to import `Control.Monad`. Howeve, using `guard` looks a bit like overkill here, you can work with a guard instead. For the `ExpAdd` and `ExpMult`, you can use `liftA2`:

```
import Control.Applicative(liftA2)
import Data.Function(on)

eval3 :: Exp -> Maybe Integer
eval3 (Const x) = pure x
eval3 (ExpAdd x y) = (liftA2 (+) `on` eval3) x y
eval3 (ExpMult x y) = (liftA2 (*) `on` eval3) x y
eval3 (ExpDiv x y)
  | Just x' <- eval3 x, Just y' <- eval3 y, y' /= 0 = pure (div x' y')
  | otherwise = Nothing
```